# How to get Real path from Uri in android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

How to get Real path from URI in android 10 and android 11. Getting the Uri from intent data i.e.

```
 private val startForResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val uri = result.data?.data
              
            }
        }
```

and intent to get pdf file

```
 val mimeType = "application/pdf"
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type = mimeType
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
 if (packageManager.resolveActivity(sIntent, 0) != null) {
            // it is device with Samsung file manager
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sIntent, "Select an PDF File")
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(intent))
        } else {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an PDF File")
        }
        try {
            chooserIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.let {
                //  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(this,"Pick MHT file"),1)
                startForResult.launch(chooserIntent)
            }
        } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "No suitable File Manager was found.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
```

Comment: What issue are you facing exactly?

Comment: I'm unable to open the pdf file within the app because of the uri, getting the uri like this content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/16 and when i try to get the real path, getting the path like this /document/16

Comment: Have you tried on a lower android version like Android 8 or 9? Is it working in the lower android version?

Comment: yes, on lower upto 8 it is working fine but on android 10 and android 11 (api level 29 and 30) it is not working, on version 8 and lower than 8 getting real path from URI using this code https://gist.github.com/MeNiks/947b471b762f3b26178ef165a7f5558a and it working fine upto version 8 but it is not working on android 10 and android 11

Comment: Do not try to get a 'real' path from that nice uri. What you got is no real path too as you have seen. Use the obtained uri directly to open the file. Further it is unclear what you try to do if you wanna open a file.

Comment: It is file viewer app, try uri also to view the file but unable to achieve it and also from uri i'm unable to get the file name, file extension etc

Answer (score 0):

We can't get _data in contentResolver.query(uri,...), so we need to find another way.

This is my code, based on table MediaStore.Files:

Be careful to add

> android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

```java
    public static String Uri2Path(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if(ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        else if(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
            String authority = uri.getAuthority();

            if(authority.startsWith("com.android.externalstorage")) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + uri.getPath().split(":")[1];
            }
            else {
                String idStr = "";
                if(authority.equals("media")) {
                    idStr = uri.toString().substring(uri.toString().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                }
                else if(authority.startsWith("com.android.providers")) {
                    idStr = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri).split(":")[1];
                }

                ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
                Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
                        new String[] {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA},
                        "_id=?",
                        new String[]{idStr}, null);
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    try {
                        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);

                        return cursor.getString(idx);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You can replace the table for your need :

```
MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("internal")
MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
MediaStore.Downloads.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
MediaStore.Downloads.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this to get the data:

`val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)`

but I am not sure you can get a usable file path from the uri.